# Find an identical function signature with different name

Tags: c#, reflection

Given an object and an instance method, I want to get a method that has the exact same signature but with a different, known name. That includes parameter list, generic parameters, possibly attributes if they're a part of the signature. How can I do that?

I know `GetMethod()` exists but I couldn't figure out which overload covers all the different possible signature variations.

Comment: Because you included the `reflection` tag -- are you hoping do make this determination at runtime?

Comment: No overload of `GetMethod` will do that, as they all take one name. You'll need `GetMethods` (plural) and filter the results.

Comment: @Marathon55 I don't mind doing it in compile time too, but I need to use this method in code so finding it in the assembly using outside tools isn't enough.

Comment: To be clear, you're trying to find this other method *on the same type*?

Comment: @JeroenMostert good point! I know the target name and rephrased the question to clarify

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes

Comment: And are you trying to mimic e.g. C#'s overload resolution rules? If so, be aware that neither generic parameters, return type or attributes are part of the signature *for that specific concept*; But in other contexts they *may* be considered part of the signature. So if you're trying to mimic some existing set of rules based on "signature", we need to know which specific set or rules you're trying to mimic.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it looks like I can't define both `void B<T>(T t)` and `void B<S>(S s)` . That doesn't happen due to overload resolution issues?

Comment: Not *specifically*, but it does relate to the fact that you'd have no (current) means of indicating at a call site which one you intended.

Comment: Is it possible to answer this question generically? I'm not sure I know enough to specify what counts and doesn't count.

Comment: Not sure if it answers your real problem, but with given: `Type givenType = ...;
      MethodInfo givenMethod = ...;
      string givenDifferentName = ...;` you can just use something like `var desiredMethod = givenType.GetMethod(givenDifferentName, Array.ConvertAll(givenMethod.GetParameters(), pi => pi.ParameterType));`. But it will not work if some of the parameters have a type which is a generic parameter defined be each generic method. __Addition:__ I suspect you consider `void NameOne<T>(T x)` and `void NameTwo<S>(S y)` to have the "same" signature?

Comment: I'm afraid I need to account for generic parameters. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but the member resolution you get with `dynamic` tries its best to mimic the C# overload rules, using the types in `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder` under the covers. Roslyn is probably more reliable, though.

Comment: Could some of the generic parameters even be `ref` or `out` or (C# 7.2) `in`? Like this `bool Example<TBad>(out TBad result)`?

Comment: No, `out` parameters are not an issue. I also have an `Expression` I got the original MethodInfo out of, if that helps with figuring out specific generic parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may work in some cases:

```
public static bool HasSameSignature(MethodInfo m1, MethodInfo m2)
{
  if (m1.GetGenericArguments().Length != m2.GetGenericArguments().Length)
    return false;

  var args1 = m1.GetParameters();
  var args2 = m2.GetParameters();
  if (args1.Length != args2.Length)
    return false;

  for (var idx = 0; idx < args1.Length; idx++)
  {
    if (!AreEquivalentTypes(args1[idx].ParameterType, args2[idx].ParameterType))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

static bool AreEquivalentTypes(Type t1, Type t2)
{
  if (t1 == null || t2 == null)
    return false;
  if (t1 == t2)
    return true;
  if (t1.DeclaringMethod != null && t2.DeclaringMethod != null && t1.GenericParameterPosition == t2.GenericParameterPosition)
    return true;
  if (AreEquivalentTypes(t1.GetElementType(), t2.GetElementType()))
    return true;
  if (t1.IsGenericType && t2.IsGenericType && t1.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == t2.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
  {
    var ta1 = t1.GenericTypeArguments;
    var ta2 = t2.GenericTypeArguments;
    for (var idx = 0; idx < ta1.Length; idx++)
    {
      if (!AreEquivalentTypes(ta1[idx], ta2[idx]))
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

So given your one method, you can do `.GetMethods()` on the type in question, and find the one whose name is correct, and for which `HasSameSignature(...)` on it and your one given method is true.

```
Type givenType = ...;
MethodInfo givenMethod = ...;
string givenDifferentName = ...;

var answer = givenType.GetMethods()
  .SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == givenDifferentName && HasSameSignature(m, givenMethod));
```